# Toggle that cycles through 3 states

Tags: javascript

I need to create one `button` that will cycle through **3 states**. For some reason that is incredible challenging to find. The functions in each state are simple style changes, example:

```
click 1: hide div
click 2: show hidden div, change bg-color
click 3: reset bg-color, change font
click 1: reset font, hide div
```

Any ideas? I can't use `jquery` (class assignment, not allowed)

Comment: Hold the state outside somewhere outside the handler; switch on the state; do the job; update the state; what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cou could use an array, with a function for each state change, and a counter variable which cycles through the possible states.

Then simply invoke the current state function through an click handler of the button.

Something like this could do it

```
var toggle = (function (el) {
    var div = document.getElementById(el); //Get the div you want to change
    var states = []; //The Array to hold the functions
    var style = {} //Will be used to save the current style
    for (var att in div.style) //Saves the style of the div *I was just lazy and did a for loop*
    style[att] = div.style[att]

    var current = 0; //The Counter

    states[0] = function () { //The first state function
        div.style["font-family"] = style["font-family"]
        div.style.display = "none";
    };
    states[1] = function () {
        div.style.display = "block";
        div.style["background-color"] = "rgb(" + [rand(), rand(), rand()] + ")"; // [1,2,3] toString is "1,2,3"
    };
    states[2] = function () {
        div.style["background-color"] = style["background-color"];
        div.style["font-family"] = "Courier New";
    }

    function rand() { //ONly to return a random number for a random bgcolor
        return ~~(Math.random() * 255)
    }
    return function () {  //The function which cycles through the states
        states[current]() //Invokes the current statechange function
        current = (current + 1) % (states.length); //Increments the counter and uses modulo to cycle
    }
})("div");

document.getElementById("click")
    .addEventListener("click", toggle);
```

Heres an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PND6m/1/)

### Update:

I modified it a bit and commented the changed code, this should be able of changing the states of multiple elements on a page

```
    function rand() {
        return~~ (Math.random() * 255);
    }


    var makeToggle = function (states, elements) { // I Changed it to makeToggle, The first argument accepts an array of states to cycle through, the second either an array of elements, or an array of objects with the element property (and an optional state function)
        var current = 0; //Sets the counter to zero

        for (var i = 0, ilen = elements.length; i < ilen; i++) {
            if (!elements[i].element) { //check if you passed an Object with the `element` Property
                elements[i] = {
                    element: elements[i] //If it was an array, the arrays element will be set to an object
                }; //to support arrays only
            }
            elements[i].style = {}; //to save the original style in the object
            for (var att in elements[i].element.style) {
                elements[i].style[att] = div.style[att]; // saves it
            }
        }

        function doForElements() { //Invokes either the state function passed with an element, or the general statefunction
            for (var i = 0, ilen = elements.length; i < ilen; i++) {
                var state = elements[i].states;
                if (state && typeof state[current] === "function") state = state[current];
                else state = states[current];
                state(elements[i].element, elements[i].style); //Invokes the function with the element as first parameter and the original style as second
            }

        }
        return function () { //Returns the function for the click handler
            doForElements();
            current = (current + 1) % (states.length); //cycles the current state counter
        };
    };

    var states = []; //Here the General State change functions get defined
    states[0] = function (div, style) {
        div.style["font-family"] = style["font-family"];
        div.style.display = "none";
    };
    states[1] = function (div, style) {
        div.style.display = "block";
        div.style["background-color"] = "rgb(" + [rand(), rand(), rand()] + ")";
    };
    states[2] = function (div, style) {
        div.style["background-color"] = style["background-color"];
        div.style["font-family"] = "Courier New";
    };


    var elements = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("div")); //To actually get an Array of the NodeList (all divs on the page)

    elements[4] = { //changes the 5th element (which should receive a special statechange function)
        element: elements[4],
        states: {
            1: function (div, style) { //Use an Objects property to pass an single state change instead of an array with functions
                div.style.display = "block";
                div.style["background-color"] = "yellow";
            }
        }
    };


    var toggle = makeToggle(states, elements); //sets the function for the click handler to toggle
    //Pass an Object with the Elements and an optional st

    document.getElementById("click")
        .addEventListener("click", toggle); //binds the function
```

Heres a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/asugax/2/) to try it out

Comment: I haven't had a change to try this yet (midterm tomorrow) but do you think it would allow me to style multiple elements on a page at the same time per state?

Comment: Just take your time =)
Sure you could, every stateChange is done through a function, in which you could simply modify as many elements you want to *(You would have to modify it a little bit)* You could also add more cycles by adding more functions to the Array, the returned function cycles through all of the `states` Array functions on every click

Comment: The very first line in the code references e1 as the parameter of the parent function. How would this change if I plan on styling more than 1 element?

Comment: @Batman I updated the Answer, if you have any question regarding the code, feel free to ask

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="mydiv" data-state="0"></div>
<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="Change State" />

var states = {
    1: [{ name: 'display', value: 'none'}],
    2: [{ name: 'display', value: 'block'}],
    3: [{ name: 'background-color', value: 'white'}, { name: 'prop', value: 'val' }]
}

window.onload = function(){
     var mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
     var mybutton = document.getElementById('mybutton');
     mybutton.onclick = function (){
         var num = parseInt(mydiv.getAttribute('data-state'));
         num = num < 3 ? ++num : 1;
         var nameValues = states[num];
         for(var i = 0; i < nameValues.length; i++)
              mydiv.style[nameValues[i].name] = nameValues[i].value;
     }
}
```

Comment: Please don't advocate the use of `onclick="..."`

Comment: Of course, the element that's hidden should not be the one that needs to be clicked to unhide.

Comment: One last note: how do you incorporate the need to change several attributes at once?

Comment: Nice, +1 for ingenuity :-)

Comment: Hi sorry I haven't replied. Bed then midterm today. I was wondering. The code above seems like it would only work if I was changing the same element on every click. What if I want to style multiple elements per click, is that possible? I may even need a 4th style to return things to normal. I have an idea of what I want to example, maybe I should just tell you guys if it helps clear things up.

Comment: If you want to change styles of multiple elements just take all the elements and iterate through them with same code